# arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc bad instruction strhlo,strhhs Cortex-A9

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, instructions

I'm very new to arm and i'm trying to compile code for arm (Cortex-A9) using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.

the only flags i use are: -mcpu=Cortex-A9 --static

In my code I wrote the following instructions:

```
strhlo r1,[sl,r0]
```

Which seems to work fine here in shellstorm assembler:
http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?inst=strhlo+r1%2C%5Bsl%2Cr0%5D&arch=arm&as_format=inline#assembly

But for some reason arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc won't compile them:

my_file.s:196: Error: bad instruction `strhlo r1,[sl,r0]'

Am I missing something?

Comment: are you in thumb mode instead of arm mode?

Comment: if you assemble it as an strh, then disassemble is it thumb or arm?

Comment: I don't actually understand thumb mode, as I read thumb instructions are 16 bit wide and my instructions seem to be 32 bit wide which means I'm not in thumb mode? how can I check that and what does it mean?

Comment: thumb2 shows as 32 bits, but the encoding up front is different the first half (not necessarily displayed first) starts with 0xF usually.  An arm instruction that does not have a conditional starts with an 0xE

Comment: but naturally you can simply look the instructions up in the arm documentation

Comment: Reading here: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/STRH--immediate--ARM-?lang=en i can use the strh instruction with the condition CC(LO): https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Conditional-execution?lang=en which means Carry clear or Less than my code can compile using the strh instruction so the condition is incorrect? and it is documented to support ARMv6T2 which i compile against

Comment: right in arm mode as shown in your link you can, but in thumb mode it doesnt work that way it is a different instruction set and encoding

Comment: armv6 supports are and thumb mode and some of the thumb2 instructions, if you are getting an error it is because you are in thumb mode most likely. the quickest way is to remove the condition assemble the code to see if there are any other errors with that instruction and then disassemble.   generally though you should know what mode from the code

Comment: So how do I change to arm mode?

Comment: there are ways to do this in thumb mode, it is not worth it to switch to arm for one instruction....show a complete example, you can possibly make the whole function arm and then there is less overhead

Comment: The function is very long, here is a code snippet of it, i can upload the entire file: `    add    r1, r3, r1, asr #5
    sub    r3, r3, r3, lsr #5
    cmp    r6, r2
    rsbhs  r6, r2, r6
    rsb    lr, r2, lr
    movlo  r8, r0
    movlo  lr, r2
    strhcc r1, [sl, r0]
    strhcs r3, [sl, r0]`

Comment: you can create a simple example from scratch for demonstration purposes, a mimimal example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: note a cortex-a9 is not an armv6 it is an armv7, which the compilers tend to default to thumb mode for...

Comment: are you feed it to gcc, are you feed it to gas, etc...minimal example...

Comment: Compile main.s using: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 main.s main.s contains the following instructions: `strhcc r1, [sl, r0]` the output: main.s: Assembler messages:
main.s:1: Error: bad instruction `strhcc r1,[sl,r0]'

Comment: your link is for an strh immediate but this is not an strh immediate this is register addressing or two register addressing.

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Instruction-Details/Alphabetical-list-of-instructions/STRH--register-?lang=en for register addressing it should also work

Comment: in general you want to refer to the ARM Architectural Reference Manual for the specific architecture (armv7-a in this case the document may be marked as armv7-ar)

Comment: these web pages can be and have countless times on this site misunderstood

Comment: try the old syntax `strloh`

Answer (score 3):

so.s

```
strhlo r1,[sl,r0]
```

try with gcc

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:5: Error: bad instruction `strhlo r1,[sl,r0]'
```

try with gas

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:5: Error: bad instruction `strhlo r1,[sl,r0]'
```

remove the conditional and the halfword

```
str r1,[sl,r0]

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a9 so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e78a1000    str r1, [sl, r0]
```

Now add the conditional

```
strlo r1,[sl,r0]

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a9 so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e78a1000    str r1, [sl, r0]
```

assembly language is specific to the assembler not the target, so what if we put the halfword after the conditional not before.

```
strloh r1,[sl,r0]

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a9 so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   318a10b0    strhcc  r1, [sl, r0]
```

Now if you had inlined this or this were thumb code then let's see what happens, maybe it works:

```
.thumb
.syntax unified
strloh r1,[sl,r0]

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a9 so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:4: conditional infixes are deprecated in unified syntax
so.s:4: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strloh r1,[sl,r0]'
```

So that is a different error message.  Which you may still run into before this is all over.

In this case it was an assembly language thing the arm assemblers (there are many from arm over the decades) might accept strhlo, but GNU assembler and gcc apparently don't.  Again the language is defined by the tool (gcc/gas) not the target (arm/thumb).

The first thing that jumped out from your question is gcc, cortex-a9 (meaning armv7-a) and that means thumb mode by default (at times difficult to get it to generate arm code).  Granted you are possibly using gcc to get at GNU assembler rather than just going to gnu assembler directly, but there was no minimal example shown (as you can see one line of code is all it takes to see what is going wrong).

---

As mentioned in the comments:

```
.thumb
.syntax unified
strh r1,[sl,r0]

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f82a 1000   strh.w  r1, [sl, r0]
```

The arm version of the unconditional instruction starts with 0xE and the thumb2 version starts with 0xF, making it easy to figure out which mode...

Comment: Isn't there a canonical answer somewhere about conditional infix vs. suffix, and what settings for which assemblers require or allow it?  Seems like that would be good to have as a duplicate target for questions like this.

Comment: Yeah, this comes up at least once a year I would say...maybe every other two.

Comment: But you can see why I keep trying to get people to understand that assembly language is tool specific not target.   Notice how even within binutils the assembly language and the disassembly do not match from a syntax perspective...And this is not uncommon with binutils.

Comment: Because tools can be created or can change every few months, you cannot truly have a canonical answer, perhaps covering popular tools up to the point of that answer, but it becomes stale.  (this specific example is quite old though yes)

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from a TL:DR: at the top about infix vs. suffix predicate conditions, instead of launching into examples and burying that key point in the middle.  Re: staleness: just mentioning the idea of placing conditions as infix  will be sufficient forever, unless someone invents somewhere *else* to put them.  (At which point someone can update a canonical answer; SO answers can be edited.)  And yes, this is a perfect example of asm source syntax being a feature of the tool, not the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Which GCC version are you using?

In old syntax, the condition codes are put between the instruction and its suffix of load/store instructions like:

```
ldmneia
ldreqd
strneb
```

Maybe you should try `strloh` instead of `strhlo`